# Remover comentários JavaScript da tag script de um HTML, ignorando conteúdo de outras tags (ex: imagens em base 64)

Tags: php, html, regex

Preciso ignorar as tags `img` pois algumas imagens vem em base64 e contêm `//` que são reconhecidas como comentários e são removidas, quebrando todo o código HTML.

```
function limpa_html($html){
    $pattern = '/(?:(?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:(?<!\:|\\\|\'|\")\/\/.*))/';
    $html = preg_replace($pattern, '', $html); //apaga comentarios em js
    return $html;
}
```

Esta é a função me atende super bem, porém imagens como
`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAAQABAAD/2wBDAAQgHBwcJCQg//` quebram o HTML. A ideia seria ignorar as tags `img` ou limitar o código apenas nas tags `script`, porém não entendo de regex a esse ponto.

[Aqui](https://regex101.com/r/8s3CE3/1) uma simulação do que acontece:

```html
<script>

// This is a comment
/* This is another comment */

// The following is not a comment
var src="//google.com"; 

</script>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQg//ejhdbjkebdklebdklenbdknedklnekdlelde>
```

No exemplo acima, o trecho final da tag `img` (`//ejhdbjkebdklebdklenbdknedklnekdlelde`) também é removido.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php#87645

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em vez de usar a regex em todo o HTML, você pode usar [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) para pegar somente as tags `script`, e aplicar a regex somente nelas.

Assim você garante que fará a substituição somente no código JavaScript, sem precisar se preocupar com as demais tags. Exemplo:

```
$text = <<<TEXTO
<script>

// This is a comment
/* This is another comment */

// The following is not a comment
var src="//google.com"; 

</script>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQg//ejhdbjkebdklebdklenbdknedklnekdlelde>
TEXTO;

// mudar o nome da função e do parâmetro para deixar bem claro o que ela faz
function limpa_comentarios($jsCode) {
    $pattern = '/(?:(?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:(?<!\:|\\\|\'|\")\/\/.*))/';
    return preg_replace($pattern, '', $jsCode); // apaga comentários em js
}

// carrega o HTML
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($text); // $text é uma string contendo o HTML
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
// procura as tags script e aplica a regex somente nelas
foreach ($xpath->query("//script") as $script) {
    $newContent = limpa_comentarios($script->nodeValue);
    // substitui o conteúdo do script
    $script->nodeValue = '';
    $script->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($newContent));
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Mas se a ideia é *minificar* o HTML/JS, talvez seja melhor procurar por [libs dedicadas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11000261), em vez de tentar fazer tudo manualmente.

Comment: Entendi o seu posicionamento porem uso um template que monta todo o HTML monta variáveis em diversas partes do HTML, por isso seria interessante incluir isso la no template, senão teria que pegar a saida do template e usar essa sua solução ai.. Na verdade a função limpa todo o HTML, deixei so a parte que esta de fato prejudicando o arquivo final..

Comment: @ThiagoCondé Então a solução ideal seria modificar o template para que ele já gerasse o código sem comentários. Se não é possível modificar o template, não tem jeito, tem que processar o HTML depois (ou então modifique a função `limpa_html` para usar `DOMDocument` e só remover o comentário das tags `script`, pelo que entendi dá na mesma) - tentar fazer uma regex que processa todo o HTML é bem mais complicado do que parece (sem contar que a regex atual já está complicada o bastante)

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda!! acho que resolvi sem querer porem terei que revisar todos comentarios a solução é adicionar um espaço entre as duas barras e os comentarios //espaçoComentario é uma solução. Mas valeu pela sua ajuda eu nem conhecia esse DOMDocument do php. Ele pode ser muito util daqui pra frente!! de qualquer forma muito obrigado!!

Comment: [RESOLVIDO] $pattern = '/(?:(?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:(?<!\:|\\\|\'|\")\s\/\/.*))/';